# InputStream closing in graph run

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have a graph that processes a large file. The file is accessed via an iterator created from the input stream.

```
for {
  in <- managed(new FileInputStream(inputFile))
} {
  // 3rd party lib that creates iterator from input stream
  val iterator = () => EntityIterator.fromPbf(in) 
  Source
    .fromIterator[OSMEntity](iterator)
    .runForeach(println)
}
```

(Here I'm using ARM, but I'm happy to hand roll the input stream management if I need to).

I expect this code to print every object in the iterator. Instead it finishes immediately because `in` is closed as soon as the ARM block is closed. Because `runForeach` doesn't block, it is closed immediately.

If I don't use ARM, when should I manually close the input stream? Or do I not need to because Akka will do it when `EOF` is reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used `scala-arm`, but remember that `runForeach` returns a `Future[Done]`. You can handle clean with `onComplete`.

```
val buf = scala.io.Source.fromFile("readme.md")
Source.fromIterator(() => buf)
  .runForeach(print)
  .onComplete {
    case Success(_) => buf.close()
    case Failure(err) => println(s"error! ${err.getMessage}")
  }
```

You should also consider Akka's `FileIO` as well!

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("readme.md"))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .runForeach(print)
  .onComplete {
    case Success(res) => println("done!")
    case Failure(err) => println(err.getMessage)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This (part 1) is what I came up with in the end. I had to do away with a Sink, and use `runForeach` instead. The `FileIO` solution doesn't work, as the parsing of the file is handled by the 3rd party lib.